# Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/redshift_adapter'

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I ran into the error when I tried to run SQL through ruby script. Can someone help me figure out what could be the cause? I already looked for some similar posts but couldn't find the right solution yet.

```
    /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require': Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/redshift_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)
  from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
  from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
  from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/pg-0.17.1/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
  from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
  from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
  from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord4-redshift-adapter-0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/redshift_adapter.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require'
  from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `rescue in require'
  from /Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
  from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
  from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:175:in `spec'
  from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
  from /Users/User/Desktop/github/tracker/app/workers/appsflyer_importer_worker_aggregate.rb:100:in `fetch_data'
  from /Users/User/Desktop/github/tracker/app/workers/appsflyer_importer_worker_aggregate.rb:120:in `perform'
  from -:30:in `<main>'
```

Here is my settings:

Gemfile

```
ruby '2.4.3'
gem 'activerecord4-redshift-adapter', '~> 0.2'
gem 'pg'
```

Ruby version

```
ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-darwin17]
```

Gem list

```
activerecord (4.2.10, 4.2.8)
activerecord4-redshift-adapter (0.2.1)
pg (1.0.0, 0.17.1)
```

Script

```
require 'active_record'

conn = {
    adapter: 'redshift',
    database: '@database',
    host: '@host',
    port: 5439,
    username: '@username',
    password: '@password'
}

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(conn)
sql = 'select count(*) from table'
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `pg` gem version `1.0.0` and it is not compatible with the version of `active_record` and `activerecord4-redshift-adapter` that you're using:

> The PGconn, PGresult, and PGError constants are deprecated, and will be removed as of version 1.0.

This can be seen in the [history](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/b9fc5da3bf0de327a56b152fc2ebfd7f249688b2/History.rdoc#L10) of the `pg` gem.

The `activerecord4-redshift-adapter` [uses both](https://github.com/aamine/activerecord4-redshift-adapter/blob/master/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/redshift_adapter.rb#L187-L191) the `PGconn` and `PGError` constants:

```
def connection_active?
  @connection.status == PGconn::CONNECTION_OK
rescue PGError
  false
end
```

Although I was unable to exactly duplicate the error message that you saw, by modifying the `Gemfile` to use an older version of the `pg` gem I was able to get farther along:

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
```

My exact steps were:

- create the `Gemfile`
- create a file `test.rb` containing your Ruby code
- run `bundle install`
- run `bundle exec ruby test.rb`

This produces the following error:

```
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activerecord4-redshift-adapter-0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/redshift_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize': could not translate host name "@host" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

This is almost certainly in the right direction for the problem you're having, and should put you on the path to accomplishing your goal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Didn't know `pg` 1.0 gem wasn't compatible with `activerecord4-redshift-adapter`

Comment: @MakotoTaguchi Please make sure you mark the answer as accepted if this has resolved the issue for you.